# Linq To Sql: Relations not correctly updated

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql, repository-pattern

**Problem summary:**

Using the same DataContext to both insert and update a User with a relation to a number of Roles, the relations are not correctly updated in my LinqToSql classes (but fine in the database). Using one DataContexts to insert and another to update works fine.

**Detailed description:**

I have a User table and a Role table in my Database. To have a many-to-many relationship between them I also have a UserRoleRelation table (with two foreign keys to User.ID and Role.ID).

I have a test where a user is created and two roles (**A** and **B**) are added to that user. Then I remove role **A** and add a new role **C** and update the user.

But when I then select the user in the database (by *DataContext.Users.Where(p => p.ID.equals(user.id)).FirstOrDefault()*) then the user only has one UserRoleRelation (to role **A**)! But everything is fine in the database - both role **A** and **C** are related to the user.

I am using Web Services and thus the Repository pattern - for each service call I create a new DataContext - however the same service might fiddle with same Object (e.g. User, UserRoleRelation or Role) more than once so that they are already attached to the DataContext - so when I attach objects to the DataContext, I am catching potential InvalidOperationExceptions (e.g. the object is already attached) and ignoring them.

In my test I use the same DataContext to insert and update the user - however, if I use two different DataContexts, then it works fine - the user is correctly retrieved from the Database!

So for some reason, the caching inside the DataContext is messed up.

Here is my UpdateUser method:

```
private User UpdateUser(User user)
{
    foreach (UserRoleRelation relation in user.UserRoleRelations)
    {
        if (relation.Role != null)
        {
            TryAttach(DataContext.Roles, relation.Role); // same as DataContext.Roles.Attach(relation.Role)
        }
    }
    // attach the new user as modified
    TryAttach(DataContext.Users, user, true); // same as DataContext.Users.Attach(user, true), but is that the correct way to do it?

    // update the relations (figure out which are removed, added and unchanged)
    IEnumerable<UserRoleRelation> oldRelations = DataContext.UserRoleRelations.Where(p => p.UserID.Equals(user.ID)).ToList();

    // mark for deletion (those elements that are in the old list, but not in the new)
    IEnumerable<UserRoleRelation> deletionList = oldRelations.Except(user.UserRoleRelations, userRoleRelationComparer).ToList();
    DataContext.UserRoleRelations.DeleteAllOnSubmit(deletionList);

    // mark for insert (those that are in the new list, but not in the old)
    IEnumerable<UserRoleRelation> insertionList = user.UserRoleRelations.Except(oldRelations, userRoleRelationComparer).ToList();
    DataContext.UserRoleRelations.InsertAllOnSubmit(insertionList);

    // attach the rest as unmodified (those that are in both lists)
    IEnumerable<UserRoleRelation> unmodifiedList = oldRelations.Intersect(user.UserRoleRelations, userRoleRelationComparer).ToList();
    TryAttachAll(DataContext.UserRoleRelations, unmodifiedList);

    DataContext.SubmitChanges();

    // return the updated user (in order to be sure that all relations are update, we fetch the user from the DB)
    User updatedUser = GetUser(user.Email); // same as DataContext.Users.Where(p => p.Email.Equals(user.Email)).FirstOrDefault();
    return updatedUser;
}
```

What am I doing wrong? - I am pretty sure that when I use the same DataContext in my test, the "attach of the user to the DataContext" throws an exception (it is already attached), and that might be why I am not getting the correct relations back - but LinqToSql should be able to spot the change in relations...

Comment: Note: In the code I expect that the list of roles on the given user are already in the database (that is why they are just attached to the DataContext).

Comment: it must be late where I am, i feel like I have an answer for you, but it's on the tip of my tongue and I can't get it off there...

Comment: You might want to paste either the DBML for the three tables or the relevant attributes on the generated class properties. Also try it without a lot of your own wrappers around methods etc. to make sure it isn't an odd scoping issue.

Comment: I wonder, if the attach method says the object is already attached you could try two things: 1) detach the attached object and then attach the object you really want to attach (instead of just ignoring the exeption); 2) try the datacontext Refresh() method, maybe that will help, you should probably specify RefreshMode.KeepCurrentValues...

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is not on the Update method but here "DataContext.Users.Where(p => p.ID.equals(user.id)).FirstOrDefault()", you are using FirstorDefault() and linq is returning only the first of the records. try removing FirstOrDefault() and saving the results on an Array...